# Is there a way to dynamically load Material Icons in native android (Java)?

Tags: android, flutter, google-material-icons

Recently i was able to dynamically load [Material Design Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) in Flutter by using the [flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons)

```dart
// First Approach
Icon icon = new Icon(Icons.settings);

// Second Approach
icon = new Icon(MaterialIcons.getIconData(Model.dynamic_icon_name);
```

[Flutter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJwgj.png)

This got me thinking if i could do something similar using a native android approach, with something like

```java
// Glide Theoretical Example
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
  .asBitmap()
  .load(MaterialIcons.getIconData(Model.dynamic_icon_name))
  .apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter())
  .into(iconView);
```

I think it would be interesting to know, since i think could provide some advantage that a developer would not need to bundle those assets with the app

Comment: 2 ways I can think of. You either have a `MaterialIcons` class in your project holding every single png URL there is and supply it to Glide or you have that class in a lib that already has every icon in its resources

Comment: @LennoardSilva Agreed, considering however many icons you would like to display at one time i think that would be the decider on whether to use let your server hosting the icons do the heavy lifting, and the be to just use Glide. implementing such, will post my outcome soon, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no effective way of handling this natively on Android, so the solution i ended up going with was having the server host these icons and i could just serve them down using Glide like this.

Step 1: Backend setup

- Download the png assets for the icon of your choice, ie: the `thumbs_up` icon from this [Material Icons link](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/thumb_up/v16/black-24dp.zip)
- Now you can go ahead and unzip the image assets into your server's assets folder, in my case this was in my public folder of the server since i was using a `Laravel` backend. In the end my icons resided in the path `public/material-icons/thumb_up_black.png` and made sure to keep a consistent naming convention `public/material-icons/{icon_name_color}.png` this was the vital point since i needed to reference these assets again.
- Now we can link the icon with the respective item

Server side

```php
...

// Creating the item
new Item::create([
  'name' => 'Like-able item',
  'icon' => 'thumb_up_black',
]);

...
```

List items API endpoint result

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Like-able item",
        "icon_url": "https//server-name.fancy/thumb_up_black.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Like-able item #2",
        "icon_url": "https//server-name.fancy/thumb_up_black.png"
    },
    ....
]
```

Step 2: Client Setup (Android app)

- Once i have consumed the API data and about to display the items, i can use `Glide` to accomplish this.

```java
ItemModel item = new ItemModel(itemDataFromServer);

Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
  .asBitmap()
  .load(MaterialIcons.getIconData(item.icon_url))
  .apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter())
  .into(iconView);
```

This was finally how i was able to solve this problem, the nice thing with this implementation was that from our three client apps (Android, iOs and Web) we could use the same if not similar method to display accordingly.